# Twitter Login with php

Tags: php, twitter

Well, basically what I need to do is log in (and register) a Twitter user on my website.
I have read a lot of Twitter libraries, forums, even here and couldn't find an answer. (Twitter api is not very friendly).

The problem that i'm having is that I **need** the e-mail of the user because my website requires it for registering an user, and I think that Twitter OAuth doesn't provide that information of the users.

The question is:
Is there anyway that Twitter (and this [Library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/) or maybe another) provide me the email of the user logued in with my app?

To end this, the reason why I'm asking here is because in Twitter libraries forums, or even in Twitter forums no one answer the question I'm asking here.

Comment: you should not need the users email address, whet to do you want it for?

Comment: edited, because my website requires the email for registering and login users.

Comment: but that's why your using OAuth, so you don't registerr them, twitter does.

Comment: that's the problem, i need to register them myself, or at least get their emails somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter does not currently provide user email addresses through their API.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6718

The only course of action is to ask for the user's email address separately in your application.

Comment: form, input, on screen, the 'usual' way ?

Comment: but the log in with twitter happens on a new window, not in my website, i cant ask for anything there.

Comment: Yea it is kind of a pain, because generally you would implement a third-party login mechanism in order to avoid having to collect additional data. But unfortunately there isn't a way to do this through Twitter. You would have to just create an additional form in your application.